Strange editors emerged
Is this normal?
About one third of the edit review queue is filled by this user and similar, and their contribution to the post typically is literally two or three changed characters. Often, the change is harmful: one post was changing from "sda" to "SDA" (in Linux disks context, where lowercase clearly makes more sense) and "1TB" to "1 TB", and that all what was changed, folks.
Another example.
Another account with the same behavior. An example of their contribution: I've changed to I have and wasn't to was not.
I don't hesitate to reject their edits with "no improvement" or even "does harm", but what they are trying to achieve? No questions, no answers, but an "editor" badge, seems to be just building a reputation, for what? It's suspicious...

I seen such kind of behavior in the past from news users, often it's a user that is not technical or they just want to "test the water", but want to build a bit of reputations to be able to have some right on the site.
It will be to check to be sure he don't abuse by over correcting typo and other type of edit from older post. He seem active on SO too. Usually the throttling system if he got rejected will work to limit such behavior if he abuse. Thanks for notifying and to let us know at the same time, as it's easy to just click accept or ignore and go on to others stuffs.

Could that be bots? Because edits clearly lack a minimal technical expertise, it's not just "non-technical user".

@NikitaKipriyanov It is possible those are bot user accounts, but this behavior has been going on for a very long time, so I think it is more likely an actual person. The users don't usually stick around long enough to get to first tier privileges +2 points at a time, largely because the amount of time required to get their is too great considering some of us will reject these edits and they are only permitted to have some number edits in queue at one time so even when the mindless Editors who approve everything there has to be one more vote to remove the proposed change.
